# What's a good JavaScript pattern for categorizing things into types?

Tags: javascript, ruby, arrays, design-patterns, associative-array

I'm looking for a way (in JavaScript) to collect a set of objects into multiple arrays, where each array contains a certain type of object, and the arrays are stored as values in an associative array, with the keys being the types. For example:

Input:

```
[<apple>, <cat>, <pear>, <mercedes>, <dog>, <ford>, <orange>]
```

Output:

```
{
  'fruit': [<apple>, <pear>, <orange>],
  'animal': [<cat>, <dog>],
  'car': [<mercedes>, <ford>]
}
```

In ruby, you could do the following:

```
things_by_type = {}
things.each do |thing|
  (things_by_type[thing.type] ||= []) << thing
end
```

which is nice and concise.

What's a good pattern for doing the same thing in JavaScript that's concise and efficient? I could do something like this, but it's not as nice:

```
var thing, things_by_type = {};
for (var i = 0; i < things.length; i++) {
  thing = things[i];
  if(things_by_type[thing.type]) {
    things_by_type[thing.type].push(thing);
  } else {
    things_by_type[thing.type] = [thing];
  }
}
```

Comment: I always thought Javascript needs a  `||=` operator. Too bad you have to type everything twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's a good pattern, but it's similar to your ruby sample:

```
var things_by_type = {};
for (var i in things) {
  var thing = things[i];
  (things_by_type[thing.type] || (things_by_type[thing.type] = [])).push(thing);
}
```

And if you can assume Javascript 1.6:

```
var things_by_type = {};
things.forEach(function(thing) {
  (things_by_type[thing.type] || (things_by_type[thing.type] = [])).push(thing);
})
```

Comment: For those who don't know, you can define `Array.prototype.forEach` if you are not using JS1.6 to work exactly the same way as if you were.

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Compatibility for a forEach implementation

Comment: **Don't** use `for..in` for arrays. It is a really bad practice.

Comment: Even without the forEach, the fourth line of the first example is nice. I forgot about assignment returning the result. Much shorter than mine. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> In ruby, you could do the following:
>
> ```
> things_by_type = {}
> things.each do |thing|
>   (things_by_type[thing.type] ||= []) << thing
> end
> ```
>
> which is nice and concise.

Actually, you can make that even nicer.

First off, `Hash.new` takes a block argument which will be called every time a non-existing key is referenced. You can use that to create that key. That way you get rid of the conditional logic inside the block.

```
things_by_type = Hash.new {|h, k| h[k] = [] }
things.each do |thing|
  things_by_type[thing.type] << thing
end
```

Secondly, what you have here is called a `fold` or `reduce`: you are "folding" or "reducing" a collection (the array of objects) into a single value (the hash, which confusingly also happens to be a collection, but is nonetheless a single value).

You can generally easily spot this pattern by looking for places where you initialize some variable, then loop over a collection and manipulate that variable at every iteration of the loop.

Ruby has folding built in, via the `Enumerable#reduce` method:

```
things.reduce(Hash.new {|h, k| h[k] = [] }) do |h, thing|
  h.tap { h[thing.type] << thing }
end
```

But what you are *really* doing, is grouping the array by the type attribute of its elements, which is also built into Ruby as `Enumerable#group_by`:

```
things.group_by {|thing| thing.type }
```

Which can be further simplified by using `Symbol#to_proc` to

```
things.group_by(&:type)
```

Unfortunately, ECMAScript doesn't have `groupBy`, nor default values for non-existing properties, but it *does* have `Array.prototype.reduce`:

```
things.reduce(function (acc, thing) {
    (acc[thing.type] || (acc[thing.type] = [thing])).push(thing);
    return acc;
}, {});
```

Comment: Thanks Jorg. Your suggestions for making the Ruby version more efficient are awesome.

Answer (score 0):

almost the same code, but works a bit different, you can use the fancy set function easier and it separates logic:

```
var a = {set:function(type,thing){
  if (this[type]) {
    this[type].push(thing);
  } else {
    this[type] = [thing];
  }
}};

a.set('a',0);
a.set('b',1);
a.set('a',2);
```